Form Builder: How to capture autocomplete field change/select event
Is it possible to capture (like in javascript) autocomplete field change/select event in Form Builder public url form page. The scenario is we want to get data to populate another field that is dependent of another field.
Example:
Car Models: has options to select
Car Model Colors: no options yet, is dependent of the first field to fetch what colors are available.

This has also been asked (and answered) in MatterMost - pls link to the thread

@petednz-fuzion Thanks for the feedback. Are there key words you suggest I search in the community chat to find them.

A bit of misunderstanding perhaps. I am flagging that you (I assume) also asked this question in MM and it would help to acknowledge that so folk can easily jump to MM to see if it has been answered instead of spending time thinking about it here. Make sense?

Is this not yours? https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/r6616hqjzp8mzn9t35mpjea65c

My bad. Thanks.

Yes, you can embed JS using below hooks
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterAngular/
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_coreResourceList/

Hi again. Going back into as it seems alterAngular is more efficient. But I am stuck in how to embed a js file or scipt into alterAngular. If you have any suggestions or a reading into suggestion, please let me know. Thank you
